# Is it possible to create a VBA macro to edit another macro within the same workbook?

Tags: vba

Is it possible to create a VBA macro to edit a specific line of another macro?

```
Sheets("Actuals Apr-18").Select
Windows("XXX Consolidated P&L 02222017.xlsx").Activate
Sheets("XXX P&L by Strategy").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(-72, 0).Range("A1").Select
```

The macro links to another spreadsheet that changes every month. The only thing that changes is the numbers. Is it possible to create a VBA macro that goes into another macro and changes a specific line?

Apologies for the dumb question.

Comment: Not a dumb question, and yes it's possible but maybe not the best solution. I'm assuming by numbers you mean `02222017`?  More details would be helpful - i.e. how you're opening this workbook in the first place, what the changed numbers would be.

Comment: Hi BigBen, I really appreciate the response! I'm opening the workbook on my desktop(?) -- not sure if that was the right response. The numbers I need to edit are indeed 0222017. They represent a date (02/22/2017). It would be nice to run a macro that changes the line Windows("XXX Consolidated P&L ...") with another macro. Is it possible to have a dialogue box open up so I can just type in whatever number I want?

Comment: By opening the workbook I meant if you were doing so programmatically and not manually. Yes you can get the date using `InputBox` or you can get the actual file via `GetOpenFilename`, among many ways to do this. My point was more that you should make the date portion of your filename dynamic - i.e. a variable - so you never really edit the macro.  SO has many examples of how to do this.

Comment: Morning BigBen, thanks again for the advice. Is it still possible to create a macro that edits the line containing 022017? Perhaps even create a dialogue box that opens up so I can type the new date in. Tbh, I'm not really that experienced.